# Special keyword lists for Elasticsearch analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

Using the standard analyzer some special words would be divided like
"Häagen-Dazs" to "Häagen" and "Daz". 
Is it possible to add a special keyword list so as to instruct Elasticsearch to treat the words as is?

Answer (score 0):

check out link from elasticsearch offcial site

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keep-words-tokenfilter.html#_settings_example

**Keep token filter**

A token filter of type keep that only keeps tokens with text contained in a predefined set of words. The set of words can be defined in the settings or loaded from a text file containing one word per line